# What file manager to use for previewing files in separate pane?

Tags: nautilus, pdf, filemanager

I work a lot with scanned documents, in PDF and PNG/JPG format. My usual workflow is:

- get new document / invoice
- scan it
- download it to my PC
- rename the scanned file, including the date of the document
- move the document to the correct folder

As you can see, I need to be able to browse a big amount of files, and do the following:

- see the document contents (first page at least). A thumbnail is not good enough: I need a full preview, in a separate pane, where I can read the document. Bonus points if the preview can be zoomed, and a multipage document can be browsed in the preview.
- the preview must be shown fast (less than 1 second). This obviously depend on the hardware: my hardware is good enough for this (I know because Windows manages this without issues)
- the preview must be shown automatically, without having to manually open / close extra windows. Just selecting a new file in the file manager should display a preview of the file in the preview pane.

By fulfilling these requirements, I am able to browse quickly the documents, rename them according to the content, move them to the correct location, and much more.

The way I do this currently in Ubuntu is to:

- browse to the document I want to see
- double click it to open it
- it appears in a new window, which I need to find, reposition and resize
- when I am done, I need to close the new window

Rinse and repeat for each document I need to browse. This does simply not scale.

Windows File Explorer offers this functionality, and works very well, but my daily system is Ubuntu, and I would like to avoid having to open Windows just for this.

I have tried several file managers, without success:

- Nautilus
- Nemo
- Thunar

The thumbnails are too small (even after max zoom), and are not shown in a separate pane, but in the file list itself.

Is there any file manager which offers the features I am looking for in Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu 18.04, but I would be willing to upgrade to 20.04 if necessary.

Comment: I guess you don't want a *file* manager, but an *image* manager. UNIX traditionally has the "one task, one tool" (or vice versa) philosophy. Programs seemingly able to display all types of file contents typically use many plugins (separate programs). That said, you could try viewing your files from the Emacs file manager ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### An alternative: Gnome Sushi

**1. Install Gnome Sushi**

```
   sudo apt install gnome-sushi unoconv
```

**2. Usage**

Select any file on nautilus and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to preview the file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to close.

You can click the button at the bottom to preview the file in fullscreen. You can also scroll up and down the file to see more pages.

[image]